# Some optimization required in snmpwalk, getting response in 5 sec from SNMP Manager . Need to reduce this time either in 1 sec or milisec?

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk

I am using this snmpwalk command to query :
snmpwalk -c public -v 2c 10.10.68.70:18089 1.3.6.1.4.1.11080.300 -t 4

port : 18089 -> where SNMP Manager is running
timeout - 4 sec

In locally , I can see the response came instantly with out any delay.
03.08.2021 18.29.57:084 230745 DEBUG   {Thread-80}SNMP run: [Thread[Thread-80,6,main]]:getNext operation on FHMR_MIB
03.08.2021 18.29.57:088 230754 DEBUG   {Thread-81}SNMP run: [Thread[Thread-81,6,main]]:getNext operation on FHMR_MIB

But in production : response is coming in 5 sec.
I checked the ping status : ping "ip" -t --> response is coming in milisec itself .

Any parameters we can optimise so that response will be faster ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing you can do on manager side. Escalate to the network administrators, so that they can check the SNMP agent configuration for you. That's often vendor dependent and can be bad topics to discuss on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the SNMP agent is under your control, then you can enable logging, run wireshark, etc to diagnose where the problem might be.